# invalid conversion from char to const char

Tags: c

so i get this conversion problem char to const char. how can i get this code to work?
please, don't use pointers because im a newbie and i dont know anything about them... Thanks :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char a[50];
int power(char a) {
    int b;
    b=0;
    if(strlen(a)-b==0)
    return 0;
    else if(a[b]=='x'){
        return power(a,b+1)+1;
    }
    else{
        return power(a,b+1);
    }
    }

}
int main()
{
  scanf("%s",&a);
  printf("%d",power(a));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're passing a `char`to a function that expects a `const char*`. If you don't know the difference you need a good book on C programming.

Comment: No. That error message should be "invalid conversion from `char *` to `char`", since you are passing an array (that decays into a pointer) where a single char is expected. **Read and understand your own code. There's no good reason for not doing so.**

Comment: @H2CO3: The `strlen` call should trigger an error like "invalid conversion from `char` to `const char*`", which is close to what's in the title.

Comment: If you're going to ask about an error message you should always copy-and-paste the exact error message and clearly indicate the line in your code that it refers to. (Don't add line numbering to your code; that just makes it more difficult for us to copy-and-paste it; use a comment on the flagged line.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`power()` should take an array (or a pointer, but you asked to keep those out, so...)

And `b` needs to be a parameter, not a variable that's always `0`.

```
int power(char a[], int b) {
    if(strlen(a)-b==0)
      return 0;
    else if(a[b]=='x'){
        return power(a,b+1)+1;
    }
    else{
        return power(a,b+1);
    }
}
```

Finally,  your `scanf()` call doesn't need a pointer to the address of the array:

```
int main()
{
  scanf("%s",a);
  printf("%d",power(a, 0));
  return 0;
}
```